# when I did "mkvirtualenv myenv" I got error

Tags: python

I have done:

- Download & Setup Python, then installed
- CMD > C:\Users\ATM Musa Thakur> python --version >> Python 3.8.5,
- CMD > C:\Users\ATM Musa Thakur> pip --version >> pip 20.2.2,
- CMD > C:\Users\ATM Musa Thakur> pip install virtualenvwrapper-win >> Successfully installed
  virtualenvwrapper-win-1.2.6.

But when I did `mkvirtualenv myenv` I got error.

> CMD> C:\Users\ATM Musa Thakur>mkvirtualenv myenv >> 'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.,

But some days before I did it without error.
Please help me to get off from this error.

Comment: try `virtualenv myenv` , as per my knowledge there is no such command like  `mkvirtualenv`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-mkvirtualenv-to-create-new-virtual-environment-python/

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, Use:

```
python -m venv myenv
```

Be sure myenv directory exist in you root directory